# What is non-Brahman said in Devi Atharvashirsha?

Tags: brahman, devi

There is Bhaumashvini (भौमाश्विनि) Yoga also known as Amrit Siddhi Yoga Today. (Ashvini Nakshatra on Tuesday). Chanting of Devi Atharvashirsha (also known as Devi Upanishad) has great significance as said in the text itself:

> भौमाश्विन्यां महादेवीसंनिधौ जप्त्वा महामृत्युं
>   तरति स महामृत्युं तरति ।
>   य एवं वेद ॥ इत्युपनिषत् ॥ २७॥
>
> Reciting it on Tuesday under
>      the asterism Ashvini, in the presence of the great Goddess, one
>      overcomes fell death - one who knows thus. This is the secret.

So, while reading it, I found that Devi said that अहं ब्रह्माब्रह्मणी and वेदोऽहमवेदोऽहम्

> अहमानन्दानानन्दौ । अहं विज्ञानाविज्ञाने ।
>   अहं **ब्रह्माब्रह्मणी** वेदितव्ये ।
>   इति चाथर्वणी श्रुतिः । अहं पञ्चभूतानि ।
>   अहं पञ्चतन्मात्राणि । अहमखिलं जगत् ॥ ३॥
>
> **वेदोऽहमवेदोऽहम्** । विद्याहमविद्याहम् ।
>   अजाहमनजाहम् । अधश्चोर्ध्वं च तिर्यक्चाहम् ॥ ४॥
>
> I am   (all forms of) bliss and non-bliss. Knowledge and ignorance are Myself. **Brahman and non-Brahman** are to be known - says the scripture of the Atharvans. I am the five elements as also what is different from them. I am the entire world. I am the Veda **as well as what is different** from it.

Here I want to know what it means by ABrahman (non-Brahman) and Aveda (non-Veda), since I think there would not be something like non-Brahman and Aveda.

Answer (score 3):

This topic shall be a bit lengthy since, I will try to answer from basics for a perfect answer built up.

```
what it means by ABrahman (non-Brahman)?
```

What is Non-Brahman, is Brahman too.

Lets us understand it in this way,

Devi expand herself, to put forth creation saying,

> एकोहं बहुस्याम                                                               (Chandogya Upanishad)

Thus, she takes the forms of all beings, Maya, jaad & Chentan everything. Thus, we can say this,
everything is Brahman.

> सर्वं खल्विदं ब्रह्म
> All this, in truth, is the Brahman.
> (Chandogya Upanishad)

Devi geeta,

> O Girirâja! This whole universe, moving and unmoving, is created by My Mâyâ S'aktî. This Mâyâ is conceived in Me. It is not, in reality, different or separate from Me. So I am the only Chit, Intelligence. There is no other intelligence than Me. Viewed practically, it is known variously as Mâyâ, Vidyâ; but viewed really from the point of Brahman, there is no such thing as Mâyâ; only one Brahman exists, I am that Brahma, of the nature of Intelligence.

Thus, this is evident that everything is Brahman as even devi says this again & again herself.

But, still what is Non-Brahman then? Remains unanswered.

Devi geeta,

> When the Supreme Self is reflected on the Impure Mâyâ or Avidyâ, He is called Jîva. **This Avidyâ conceals Brahma**, Whose nature is Happiness; therefore this Jîva is the source of all miseries.

When, Brahman is concealed by Maya, one experiences Non-Brahman, due to conflugence of sense & intellect.

This can be best explained by citations from Vidya Geeta of Tripura Rahasya,

Shree devi says,

> Everything fit to be worshipped is my supreme manifestation, but the ignorant do not know me, as they are surrounded by my mystic power of illusion.
> Distinguished sages, although of the nature of non dual awareness, I manifest in this boundless universe.
> Through my own illusionary power, I create my own ignorance, I'm subjected to mundane existence for a long time, untill becoming a student & getting knowledge of true self from a guru.
> Although eternally free, I become liberated anew. Although free from the desire for diverse existence, I create this diverse world.

Devi geeta,

> This Avidyâ(Maya) and nothing else, is the cause of the difference in Jîvas, by creating differences in their bodies, indriyas (organs) and minds. Again, due to the varieties in the three Gunas and their wants, Mâyâ also appears various.

> The Great Self is the only Supreme Thing in this world of Mâyâ (Illusions). He it is that under the various Upâdhis of an actor and enjoyer performs various functions leading to the Dharma (righteousness) and the Adharma (unrighteous). Then he goes into various wombs and enjoys pleasure or pain according to his Karma. Then again owing to the tendencies pertaining to these births he becomes engaged in various functions and gets again various bodies and enjoys varieties of pleasures and pains. O Best of Mountains! There is no cessation of these births and deaths; it is like a regular clockwork machine; it has no beginning and it goes on working to an endless period. Ignorance or Avidyâ is the Cause of this Samsâra.

Devi uses the snake rope analogy,

> Wherever there is anything, seen or heard, I always exist there, within and without, There is nothing moving or unmoving, that can exist without Me. If there be such, that is like the son of a barren woman. Just as one rope is mistaken for a snake or a garland, so I am the One Brahma and appears as Îs'vara, etc. There is no doubt in this. This world cannot appear without a substratum. And That Substratum is My Existence. There can be nothing else.

Again devas use the Snake rope analogy here,

> We bow down with great devotion to Thee, the Goddess of the Universe, the Creatrix of Mâyic Avidyâ (the Nescience) under whose influence this world is mistaken as the rope, as a garland is mistaken for a rope and again that mistake is corrected by whose Vidyâ.

Thus, as we all know the snake rope analogy, similarly the person bounded by sense & Avidya(Maya) percives everything as different from self. Thus, categorizing it into Non-Brahman.

Therefore, this can finally be concluded that under Avidya (Maya) the person cannot percieve Brahman. And what comes to his experience, is what Non-Brahman is.

```
Aveda (non-Veda), since I think there would not be something like non-Brahman and Aveda.
```

Vedic are those who are astik & believed in superiority of Vedas alone. The 6 darshans are included in this.
There are definetly some non-vedic elements too.
These are due to 2 factors, first due to the path choosen (Astik) & second due to the difference in philosophies (Nastik).
Former, are the people who are diksit in Tantric sampradaya. They accept the fundamentals of vedas & even quote mandalas from vedas & Upanishads, but just choose a different path of Tantra to realize it. (Other than 6 darshans of Vedic path) (Thus Astik).
They agree to the Vedas, but for them Tantras are the Vedas. Thus, they don't follow Vedic paths. Some, tantric kulas like Vamacharis, Kaulas, Aghoris & Kapaliks even remove Yagnopavit after Dikshabhishekam as they are no longer bind to the identity of body & varna by birth.

But, Agamas & Vedas don't contradict to each other, but instead follow the same fundamental of Parbrhaman. But, just because they consider Tantra >>>> Vedas, & difference in fundamental path. They too are called non vedic.

The second people are Charvakas, or Mllechas, who completely disagree from Vedas & their superiority.(Nastiks, who are non-vedic in true sense)

> kiṃ vēdāntāpuḍhēṃ cā0 || kiṃ śaṅkarāpuḍhēṃ maśyaka ||

> चार्वाकाणामिवैषां हि भयं न परलोकतः

Thus, it is evident that they believe that death alone gives moksha, and doesn't have a need to fear about hell or heavens.

But, how can devi be Non-vedic too?

Durga Saptashati,

> एकैवाहम् जगत्यत्र द्वितीया का मामापरा।
> पश्यैता दुष्ट मय्येव विशन्त्यो मद्विभूतयः।।                    अहमेवास्मि सकलं मदन्यो नास्ति कश्चन।।
> I alone exist in this entire Universe, no one is besides me. Oh wicked one, it is myself who appeared in many forms. I am everything that exist, nothing exist besides me.

This explains, that everyone is her. Be, it Astik, nastik, mleecha, chandala, etc.

I remember once, a sadhaka of devi extolled her saying,

> You, yourself manifested as Agamas and their knowledge, to let your Sadhakas cross the endless seas of miseries. You, inspired Brihaspati to delude asuras by putting forth Charvaka philosophy. Thereby, Oh, devi maintaining the balance of Universe.

Now we shall see devi as deity of words & thoughts. And the reason is explained at last.

Yagnavalkya praises Bhagwati as,

> My sincere obeisances to you Brahma Swarupa, Parama Devi, Jyoti Rupa, Sanatani and the **Adhishthaari(ruler) of all Vidyaas**.
> You are the ‘Adhishthaana Devata’ or the Reigning Deity of ‘Visarga’, ‘Bindu’ and ‘Maatra’ indicative of a half-word, a nil-word and a measure of a word which constitute the rudiments of a Great Piece of Writing or Speech! You are the basis of ‘Sankhya’ and ‘Ganita’ or the numbers and measuring units without which there could be no counting or accounting and the quantification and evaluation. Devi! You are the embodiment of Power of Memory, Power of Knowledge, Power of Mind and Power of Imagination or Thoughts. You are the Ruler of Tongue, Mind, Thought, Speech and any thing to do with brains.

Words are the form of Bhagwati, herself.
This can be proved with Pramanas from Prapanchsara Tantra as said by Narayana himself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

A few lines from hymn to Prakriti in Prapanchasara tantra, extolling devi as form of shabda,

> A hymn is composed of sentence
> And these of words with their terminations.
> Words again consist of letters
> And thou thyself, oh Supreme queen,art of the letter
> Thus art Thou both the hymn & those who hymn thee.
> Salutations to thee are lady Supreme over all,
> Who art bindu.
> Intelligence memory speech mind and knowledge.
> Oh destructor of ills, thou art Bindu & Nada.
> Thou art spoken as of memory and knowledge.

But what link does Shabda or Akshar has to this topic of discussion?
The reason is, be it any Sampradaya, be it Vedic, Tantra dikshit, Meelach, or Chandala. Not, just humans, even Animals counts here. Everyone have thoughts and sound which is nothing but Shabhdas.
The alone idea, of being either Astik or Nastik arises from 4 Vaks. (Vaikhari, Madhyama, Pashyanti, Para). Thus even thou one doesn't approve the fact of being astik still the person is pervaded by Devi in all states.           Even, the 4 states of awareness are pervaded by Devi.
Who can escape her?
She is all pervasive...

Thus, it is evident that she is everything, that one can think of be it even non-vedic too.
Once again citing from Devi geeta,

> Wherever there is anything, seen or heard, I always exist there, within and without, There is nothing moving or unmoving, that can exist without Me. If there be such, that is like the son of a barren woman.

**कालिकार्पणमास्तु ।**